# Fixing 413 Request Entity Too Large Errors :

Tags: python, http, jupyter-notebook, ibm-watson, cloudant

When I tried to save the data in the cloudant database from watson studion using spark & python environment, I got this error "HTTPError: 413 Client Error: Request Entity Too Large document_too_large " How could I fix Error 413?

My code:

```
def db_data_writing(credential:dict, db_name:str, files:dict):
    """
    DB data writing
    This function reach the online database and write the input files as a new document
    Parameters
    ----------
    credential: dict
                credential to access the online Cloudant database instance
    db_name: str
                name of the database on which write data
    files: dict
                json containing data to write on db
    Returns
    -------
    bool
        exit status
    """
    # Feed credential and establish a connection
    client = Cloudant.iam(credential['username'],credential['apikey'],connect=True)
    # Select the database instance on which write results
    db = client[db_name]
    # write and save document
    db.create_document(files).save()
    # shutdown the connection
    client.disconnect()

credential={xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
db_name = "xxxxxxxxx"

for k in range(len(dataPreparation.index)):# type of dataPreparation is DataFrame
    print(dataPreparation.loc[k])
    i+=1
    db_data_writing(credential, db_name, dataPreparation.loc[k] )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cloudant imposes limits on document sizes and also on the total request body size. A document must not be larger than 1MB, and a request body must be no larger than 11MB. If you exceed either of those, you will get a 413 error back.

These limits are there "for your own protection". Even using documents approaching 1MB is somewhat suboptimal -- you really should try to keep documents within a few kB to hit the performance sweetspot when using Cloudant.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-documents

So to work around this you need to revisit your data model and ensure your documents are smaller than 1MB.